# Is ActivityCompat and ContextCompat interchangeable?

Tags: java, android

This is a snippet of the code to request for permission to access fine location in device.

```
if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1);

    } 

...
```

If instead I switched ContextCompat with ActivityCompat vice versa, would my code still function as desired? For instance,

```
if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){

    ContextCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1);

} 

...
```

I know ContextCompat is a subclass of ActivityCompat, but what determines when to use ContextCompat or ActivityCompat as they both share the same methods?

Answer (score 1):

There's no trade-off really. Not sure why they wrote so - checkSelfPermission() is a method of ContextCompat and ActivityCompat is subclass (child) of ContextCompat so you can pass either one whenever object of ContextCompat class is required.

[refer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActivityCompat.html)